# Get order between two status

Tags: magento, magento2, history, status

I have a problem in getting the sum of time taken between an order

I can able the get the created time by the following code:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_status_history_collection')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('created_at')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('eq'=>'complete'))
    ->load()
```

is there a way to get the sum of time taken between two status like sum(OrderInvoiced+OrderShipped) ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the direct `SQL` queries method to get the time difference between invoice and shipment created.

[Magento Direct SQL Queries](https://fishpig.co.uk/magento/tutorials/direct-sql-queries/)

Invoice is saved under `sales_flat_invoice` and shipment are saved under `sales_flat_shipment`. There are 2 dates for each `created_at` and `updated_at` in both tables.

Here is the `SQL` query to get the difference between invoice and shipment based on `created_at` column

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF(ss.created_at,si.created_at) As TimeTaken 
FROM `sales_flat_invoice` si 
JOIN `sales_flat_shipment` ss 
ON si.order_id=ss.order_id 
WHERE si.order_id=1
```

To get the time difference for all the order just remove `WHERE si.order_id=1` from the above query.